# How to set multiple option list and extensions in DT::datatable

Tags: r, datatables

I tried to apply [datatable options and extensions](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) to plot a [table](http://rpubs.com/englianhu/test_datatable). Its work if follow the reference but ColVis doesn't work when I combined / applied multiple extensions. Any idea?

```
df %>% 
  datatable(., caption="Table 3.4.1 : Partial Matching Teams' Name.", 
            extensions=list('ColReorder','ColVis', list(FixedColumns=list(leftColumns=2))), 
            options=list(autoWidth=TRUE,
                         dom='C<"clear">lfrtip',
                         colVis=list(exclude=c(0, 1),
                         activate='mouseover'),
            colReorder=list(realtime=TRUE),
            scrollX=TRUE,
            scrollCollapse=TRUE))
```

Comment: Any solution on the TableTools doesn't work? Here I provides the temporariry link which can test if the buttons are workable?
<http://rpubs.com/englianhu/testing>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [DT manual](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) options associated with some extensions needs to be placed in a named list. If one specifies options in `options` attribute, then `NULL` must be assigned.

```
datatable(.,extensions=list("ColReorder" = NULL,
                            "ColVis" = NULL,
                            "FixedColumns"=list(leftColumns=2))
```

Another error is generated due to insufficient `dom` attribute. For more info [see this link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) . Each letter in `dom` is linked with specified element of table output. Uppercase letters associated with `extension` and lowercase with table elements (`R` - Col**R**eorder, `C` - **C**olVis, `T` - Table**T**ools, `t` - **t**able, `i` - table **i**nfo  etc.). In case example 'R' is missing, and therefore Col**R**eorder couldn't work. Putting all together below correct code with TableTools added:

```
iris %>% 
  datatable(
    extensions = list("ColReorder" = NULL,
                      "ColVis" = NULL,
                      "TableTools" = NULL,
                      "FixedColumns" = list(leftColumns=2)), 
    options = list(autoWidth=TRUE,
                   oColReorder = list(realtime=TRUE),
                   oColVis = list(exclude=c(0, 1),   activate='mouseover'),
                   oTableTools = list(
                   sSwfPath = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
                   aButtons = list("copy","print",
                                   list(sExtends = "collection",
                                        sButtonText = "Save",
                                        aButtons = c("csv","xls")))),
               dom = 'CRTrilftp',
               scrollX = TRUE,
               scrollCollapse = TRUE))
```

**Upgrade!**
As DT has upgraded (v0.1.56) extensions `TableTools` and `ColVis` is no longer available. According to the new [tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) above extension are possible through `buttons` extension. New version of package is more consistent and adding extensions is easier than before:

```
 DT:::datatable(
    iris,
    escape=F,
    filter = "top",
    rownames= F,
    extensions = list("ColReorder" = NULL,
                      "Buttons" = NULL,
                      "FixedColumns" = list(leftColumns=1)),
    options = list(
                dom = 'BRrltpi',
                autoWidth=TRUE,
                lengthMenu = list(c(10, 50, -1), c('10', '50', 'All')),
                ColReorder = TRUE,
                buttons =
                  list(
                    'copy',
                    'print',
                    list(
                      extend = 'collection',
                      buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
                      text = 'Download'
                    ),
                    I('colvis')
                  )
              )
    )
```

Comment: Just wonder why unable download as well, http://rpubs.com/englianhu/natural-language-analysis. Kindly look into it?

Comment: Hi, I've been able to download data from your tables. I've tested on linux and Mac. Everything seems to work. Maybe I misunderstood something. Regards

Comment: I tried to run the latest upgrade coding above but there prompt me below error on css : `Error in match.arg(style, list.files(depPath("datatables", "css"))) : 
  'arg' should be one of “dataTables.bootstrap.extra.css”, “dataTables.bootstrap.min.css”, “dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css”, “dataTables.foundation.min.css”, “dataTables.jqueryui.min.css”, “dataTables.material.min.css”, “dataTables.semanticui.min.css”, “dataTables.uikit.min.css”, “jquery.dataTables.extra.css”, “jquery.dataTables.min.css”`

Comment: I've been using on R 3.3.0 and DT v0.1.56. Do you have the same Sir?